Question About the Meaning of Notations: Big "O", $\leq$, $\lesssim$, $\approx$, $\lessapprox$, etc. in Combinatorics
I am completely new to combinatorics. I start to self-study some combinatorics but got confused in the very beginning. I came upon the following:

$X\lesssim Y$ means that as $X$ and $Y$ grow large, typically as a function of some parameter, say $N$, there exists a positive constant $C$, which does not depend on $N$, such that $X\leq CY$. This is also sometimes written $X=O(Y)$, and is read $X$ is big "$O$" of $Y$, or on the order of $Y$. Furthermore, $X\approx Y$ means that $X\lesssim Y$ and $Y\lesssim X$. We write $X\lessapprox Y$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $C_{\epsilon}>0$ such that $X\leq C_{\epsilon}N^{\epsilon}Y$. For example, $N\log^{100}N\lessapprox N$. This notation is not only more convenient, but it also emphasizes the fact that these constants do not affect our results asymptotically.

Basically, I couldn't get what does these notations mean. I couldn't figure out $N\log^{100}N\lessapprox N$ either. They are very different from the things that I am familiar with (e.g., analysis and topology). Could someone please explain them to me, preferably using examples and providing intuitions? Thanks a lot in advance!

Note that they are only expressions that if you add a few symbols here and there, become inequalities. Until you build up intuition, do the mechanical translation into the corresponding inequalities. For example $N\log^{100}N\lessapprox N$ is the same as "for every $\epsilon>0, \exists C_\epsilon>0$ such that $N\log^{100}N\leq C_\epsilon N^\epsilon N$. Then, play with this one. For example, can we bound $\frac{\log^{100}N}{N^\epsilon}\leq C_\epsilon$.

@ameg Thanks for your comment! And I know this might not be a good reply from me, but I honestly still can't see where this is going.

Then the problem is not with the notation, but with inequalities. There is an idea that sometimes helps and is that limits yield inequalities. Are you able to compute the limit of $\frac{\log^{100}N}{N^\epsilon}$ when $N\to\infty$ ? Note that if that limit exists, then there is a constant $C_\epsilon$ bounding it. It is not the only technique, but in this case it works. There is also not a single technique that will solve all such problems.

Well, for all $\epsilon>0$ the limit is zero (log grows, but too slow). You could do something like L'Hospital.

Where is this notation coming from? Their definition of Big O could be more precise, it's missing the part that $CY$ has to bound $X$ only after some $N_0$ in the domain of $X$ (presumably this is what they mean with "as $X$ and $Y$ grow large").

@RandyMarsh It's from The Erdo ̋s Distance Problem by Garibaldi, Iosevich, and Senger. Do you mean that I should view the $X$ and $Y$ as sequences, say ${X_n}$ and ${Y_n}$; then $X\lesssim Y$ means there exists a $C>0$ such that $X\leq CY$ for all but finitely many $n$?

Yes, that's a correct definition of Big-O for sequences (typically one also assumes that $X$ and $Y$ are positive). It's about asymptotic behavior, so $X$ might be wild at the beginning, but eventually gets dominated by $CY$.

@RandyMarsh So the "parameter" $N$ is discrete (not continuous) and can only be positive integers?

Not necessarily. You can define it on functions $f,g\colon U\to [0,\infty)$ where we say that $f$ is $O(g)$ if there exists $c>0$ and $u_0\in U$ such that $f(u)<c\cdot g(u)$ for all $u>u_0$. Here $U$ can be any infinite subset of $\mathbb R$, but depending on context it is either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb N$ (which is very common in algorithm analysis).

@RandyMarsh Thank you very much for the clarification!
